# How to fix overheating and battery low life on ASUS K56CM?

Tags: battery, overheating

I have an ASUS K56CM ubuntu 12.04 runs well, but the temperature in idle is about 55-65 °C. And also my battery have a half less life then on windows7. I tried Jupiter but it doesn't work. Should I try a another version of Linux?

Comment: how much memory you have ?

Comment: 8 GB RAM memory

Comment: pls try to see this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/152453/how-to-reduce-the-fan-noise-and-how-to-increase-battery-life?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could try TLP and see if that improves your battery life and temperatures. I've observed almost a 2X battery life improvement on my Lenovo X131e running Kubuntu.

http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. So and what ubuntu version should I use: 12.04LTS or 13.10? or another?